# Retirar o ultimo nome de uma celula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma tabela com o nome completo de utilizadores e precisava de nutra coluna colocar o ultimo nome, alguém me ajuda com a formula?

> A2 = Ricardo Simoes
>
> B2 = Simoes

Tenho tentado assim mas da-me erro

```
=EXT.TEXTO(A2;LOCALIZAR(" ";A2;1)+1;NÚM.CARACT(A2)-LOCALIZAR(" ";A2;1))
```

Comment: `=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","*",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")))))`

Comment: Nao deu, traduzi para pt  
=Direita(A2,NÚM.CARACT(A2)-LOCALIZAR("*",SUBST(A2," ","*";NÚM.CARACT(A2)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBST(A2," ",""))))) e deu erro :( @Earendul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe  também a opção de criar uma função para pegar o último nome da célula, como você quer. No código a seguir uso o "For" para percorrer o conteúdo da célula até encontrar um espaço em branco "" e, enquanto isso, a variável "p" vai sendo incrementada, para sabermos qual o tamanho do último nome. Depois é só usar a função "Right" para pegar o último nome e a função "Trim" para retirar os espaços me branco.

Para inserir o módulo:
Alt - F11
Inserir módulo

Código da função:

```
Function UltimoNome(Nome As Variant) As String
Dim p As Integer
For i = 0 To Len(Nome) - 1
p = p + 1
If Mid(CStr(Nome), Len(CStr(Nome)) - i, 1) = " " Then
Exit For
End If
Next
UltimoNome = Trim(Right(Nome, p))
End Function
```

A utilização da função no planilha seria simples.

```
=UltimoNome(A2)
```

Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma usando somente funções nativas do Excel (a fonte original é [esta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/350390/2896619)) é assim:

```
=DIREITA(A2;NÚM.CARACT(A2)-PROCURAR("|";SUBSTITUIR(A2;" ";"|";NÚM.CARACT(A2)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A2;" ";"")))))
```

Detalhamento de como funciona, da esquerda para a direita:

- `NÚM.CARACT(A2)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBSTITUIR(A2;" ";""))` - conta o número total de espaços na string original
- `SUBSTITUIR(A2;" ";"|"; ... )` – Altera apenas o último espaço para o caractere `|`, para diferenciá-lo dos demais (note que a sua string original não pode conter um caractere desse, senão a fórmula não funciona corretamente).
- `PROCURAR("|"; ... )` – Encontra a posição absoluta daquele caractere `|` adicionado (e que era o último espaço na string original)
- `DIREITA(A2;NÚM.CARACT(A2) - ... ))` – Devolve todos os caracteres depois daquele caractere `|` (ou seja, a última palavra inteira na string original)

**Além disso, como você está usando o Excel em português (onde a vírgula é usada como separador decimal), você precisa usar o ponto-e-vírgula como separador de parâmetros na fórmula.**

A resposta original no SOen tem também sugestões de como contornar o caso em que não exista nenhum espaço em branco na string original (além do uso das vírgulas, pode ser que esse seja o seu "novo" erro mencionado em comentário).

> P.S.: Aliás, essa resposta é basicamente a mesma solução sugerida pelo
>   @Earendul em um comentário, apenas traduzida para o Excel em português.
>   Salvo uma grande coincidência, o crédito original ainda é do autor da resposta lá no SOen.

Comment: Da erro diz que o valor tem de ser inferior a 50 caracteres @Luiz Vieira

Comment: Qual é a string que você está usando pra teste?

Comment: Ah, eu editei a resposta porque tinha um espaço a mais na fórmula (algum erro na hora de copiar e colar aqui).

Comment: Voltei a tentar com a nova string e devolve que o valor tem de ser igual ou inferior a 50 caracteres

Comment: Sim, eu entendi. Mas qual valor? A mensagem de erro é *exatamente* essa? Eu fiz testes aqui com nomes fictícios com 150 caracteres e funciona como esperado. Se você não explicar melhor, fica difícil ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Inspirado na resposta do Denis Caixeta, escrevi uma função:

```
Function UltimoNome(Nome As Variant) As String
    For Posicao = (Len(Nome) - 1) To 0 Step -1
        If (Mid(Nome, Posicao, 1) = " ") Then
            UltimoNome = Mid(Nome, Posicao + 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Ela varre o nome do final para o início até encontrar um espaço em branco. Encontrado o espaço, ela retorna o que estiver após ele (o último nome).

Essa função pode ser utilizada da mesma maneira que a do Denis:

```
=UltimoNome(A2)
```

Exemplo:

```
=UltimoNome("Antônio Vinícius Menezes Medeiros")
```

Retorna:

```
Medeiros
```

Answer (score 0):

Em português é melhor utilizar a fórmula `SUBST`

```
=DIREITA(A3;NÚM.CARACT(A3)-PROCURAR("|";SUBST(A3;" ";"|";NÚM.CARACT(A3)-NÚM.CARACT(SUBST(A3;" ";"")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Baseando-me do código passado pelo António Vinícius Menezes
Abaixo segue um código adaptado para dados de origem de banco de dados:

```
dim A as Integer 
dim i as Integer
dim Nome as Variant
dim PrimeiroNome as Variant
dim UltimoNome  as Variant


'Aqui alimentamos a variável Nome com o nome vindo do banco de dados
Nome = rs.Fields("nome_estudante")

'Extrair o último nome do nome completo
For A = (Len(Nome) - 1) To 0 Step -1
    If (Mid(Nome, A, 1) = " ") Then
        UltimoNome = Mid(Nome, A + 1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'Extrair os Primeiros Nomes do nome completo
For i = 1 To Len(Nome)
    If (Mid(Nome, i, 1) = " ") Then
        PrimeiroNome = Left(Nome, A - 1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Se gostou marque como uma resposta importante! Valeu